# Django @permission_required Decorator not Working

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use use `@permission_required` decorator and for some reason the decorator is being completely ignored. I can even misspell the permission and I get no errors, nothing. The user I'm testing is not admin and has no permissions, yet, the view is being processed like the decorator is not even there.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('my_app.change_model', login_url="/login/")
def myview(request):
# my view here
```

If I'm not logged in, I'm correctly redirected to the `/login/` page. However, once I'm logged in, the permission check is being ignored and the view is processed for all logged in users without any permission.

Comment: your app is called `my_app ?`

Comment: yes, the app is called my_app. But I get no error even if I write `@permission_required('blah.blah', ...` and I'm not forwarded to the `/login/` page either. Its like its not even there ...

Comment: If your user is a superuser, then this situation is normal.

Comment: unfortunately, the user is not superuser nor admin, just a regular user with no permissions.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am stuck on this exact problems

Comment: inside permission required decorator give your model name in the 'change_model'.  for example 'change_country' i.e. country is the model name in this case

Answer (score 0):

Inside permission required decorator give your model name in the 'change_model'. for example 'change_country' i.e. country is the model name in this case. Workflow that I followed is that, I have created a group called 'General' and given this group a permission to create countries. I also created a test user under the 'General' group. I used django administration feature. And to test the end result, I have logged in with the test user.

It worked like a charm, sharing snipped of code below as a hint:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('appname.add_country')
def countryCreate(request, template_name='appname/country/create.html'):
    # your code goes here...
```